# MySQL Join Performance Differences

Tags: join

if you compare all the Joins that we have in MySQL, which takes the shortest time to get executed... PLease let me know if the question holds grounds and that if I m right in asking this..

Comment: That question depends on what indexes you have, how many columns you are joining on

Comment: i m not talking abt the practical performances. If u take into account of the exact time taken, which is faster. Actually I saw this as a question in some websites. So asking u out of curiousity..

Answer (score 0):

There is, for practical purposes, no difference in performance between two particular *types* of joines. Obviously the data and indexes involved will have an impact, but constructing an left or right, inner or outer join that involves the same data and the same indexes should not be measurably different.